# How can I pass a pointer as a parameter to a function in COM object?

Tags: c++, qt, dll

```
Adaptor->dynamicCall("GetWPlace(long, long*, long*, BSTR*)", i, &DevplaceId,&DevplaceNum,&WPComments);
```

I have error

> QVariant::QVariant(void*)' is private

whats wrang? 
I use Qt 4.8.4

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I am frim Russia and I now English very bad, I want to use COM dll library. I have created QAxObject *Adaptor; for this. When I pass simple argument all is well, but a want to pass pointer

Answer (score 0):

**Answered on ru.stackoverflow, just translating my answer**

According to the documentation of `QAxBase::dynamicCall()` it accepts function parameters as `const QVariant&`. The compiler doesn't know how to convert `long*` to `QVariant` (the `QVariant` class doesn't have the corresponding methods). Possible solutions:

1. Try `QAxBase::generateDocumentation()`. May be there's a similar function that doesn't use pointers;
2. Pass `long*` in a `QVariant`;
3. Use `queryInterface()` and call the function directly.

Though case 1 is relatively clear, case 2 is described in the following sample code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    long dig = 12345;
    long* digPtr = &dig; // The pointer
    qDebug() << digPtr; // Check pointer value in debug
    // Convert long* to QVariant
    QVariant var = qVariantFromValue((void*) digPtr);
    // Convert QVariant в long*
    long* ptr = (long*)var.value<void *>();
    qDebug() << ptr; // Check the ponter value

    return a.exec();
}
```

The original solution: http://blog.bigpixel.ro/2010/04/storing-pointer-in-qvariant/.
Case 3 is described in the documentation to `QAxBase`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaxbase.html